# how can I put an image in a post with original size

Tags: posts, images

whenever I put an image into a post, it always appears in smaller size than original, only after clicking on the image it opens in full size, how can I manage to post original size images in post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [Attachment Display Settings](https://codex.wordpress.org/Inserting_Images_into_Posts_and_Pages#Step_5_.E2.80.93_Attachment_Display_Settings) there is a size dropdown.

Set it to 'FULL SIZE' when you add your image.

[image]

[image]